# How to handle array of structures in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, static, void

I made a `struct`:

```
public struct Triangle
{
    public Triangle(double LP0x, double LP0y, double LP0z, double LP1x, double LP1y, double LP1z, double LP2x, double LP2y, double LP2z)
    {

    }

    public void Render()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("PROCESSING:\n"+    LocalPoint0[0].ToString() + LocalPoint0[1].ToString() + LocalPoint0[2].ToString() + "\n" + 
                                            LocalPoint1[0].ToString() + LocalPoint1[1].ToString() + LocalPoint1[2].ToString() + "\n" +
                                            LocalPoint2[0].ToString() + LocalPoint2[1].ToString() + LocalPoint2[2].ToString());

    }
}
```

Then I put this into array:

```
static Triangle[] MODEL = new Triangle[12]{
                               new Triangle(1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1),
                               new Triangle(1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1),
};
```

Then I tried to handle it:

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    MODEL[i].Render();
}
```

but all 12 times msgbox from `Render()` function says, that it "renders" always first triangle(MODEL[0]).

Comment: What is `LocaPoint0`, `LocalPoint1`, and `LocalPoint2`?

Comment: You've left out some code that may be important to the question - the code for the constructor and where `LocalPoint[x]` is defined.

Comment: Can we see everything from Triangle that is relevant to this issue?  The way LocalPoints are declared could be your problem.

Comment: I was writing the same questions, why don't show the complete Triangle struct?

Comment: I don't think the Triangle constructor code matters based on the second code sample.

Comment: Looking at the constructor, it can be inferred that `LocalPointx` is an array that holds the x, y, and z values.  Assuming the arrays are part of the struct, then the code as posted should work.  If it's not, then some other code is interferring.  Without a complete code snippet that can be reproduced, it's a guessing game.

Comment: post the real code that does not work

Comment: STRUCT: http://pastebin.com/JgAreKm4  FULL CODE: http://pastebin.com/3wH0Yi63

Comment: The arrays are in the struct but they're declared as `static` - which means there's only one copy of each array regardless of how many structures you create.  Get rid of the `static` modifier.

Comment: i cant remove "static", otherwise i cant define array

Comment: Create the array in the constructor

Comment: @G0867532 - What?  That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @G0867532 that because you don't have static data to declare it with. use the constructor to instantiate the arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare something as [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx), it becomes shared between all instances of your object. First remove the static modifier form your struct properties, then you can create the arrays in your constructor instead:

```
private struct Triangle
{
    double[] LocalPoint0;
    double[] LocalPoint1;
    double[] LocalPoint2;

    public Triangle(double LP0x, double LP0y, double LP0z, double LP1x, double LP1y, double LP1z, double LP2x, double LP2y, double LP2z)
    {
        LocalPoint0 = new double[3];
        LocalPoint1 = new double[3];
        LocalPoint2 = new double[3];
        //snip
    }
}
```